# the difference between os.mkdir() and os.makedirs()

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I use Python2.7 to create a Spider in PyCharm to get data from website.
In the first spider I create a Spider in the project folder and use `os.mkdir('home/img/')` to create a folder to save data. There is no error.

In the second spider I create the spider with RedisQueue which is in the project folder and put the *Spider.py* into */usr/lib/python2.7*. When I use `os.mkdir('home/img/')` it reports the error

> no such file or dir

and I change it to `os.makedirs()` which works.

May I know why the 1st one doesn't meet error?

Comment: mkdirs() will create any necessary "middle" directories in the specified path, mkdir() won't. you sure your code is running with a proper "current" directory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**os.makedirs()** : Recursive directory creation function. Like
**os.mkdir()**, but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.

What this means is that you should not try to create nested directories with `os.mkdir()` but use `os.makedirs()` instead.

In your case, I am guessing that you want to create a directory under your home directory, in which case you would need something like `os.mkdir("/home/img")`, which will fail if you do not have enough permissions.

You could try and do something like: `os.chdir('/home')` and after that `os.mkdir('img')` so you create *home/img* in steps! Good luck!

Comment: Link to the **os.makedirs()** documentation (Python 2): [https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Answer (score -2):

Difference between os.mkdir(dirname) and os.mkdirs(dirname)

mkdir() will create only neaded directory. If some of parent directories was not existing, mkdir() will return false. mkdirs() will create the last directory with all missing parent directories.so mkdirs() is more handy.